# Multiresolutional wavelet decomposition code

Tags: algorithm, math, decomposition, wavelet, dwt

I am not an advanced mathematical, so I understand only the basics of wavelet decomposition. I found [JWave](http://code.google.com/p/jwave/), which is a Java implementation of wavelet processing. The author tells me it can by its nature to multidimensional decomposition.

The problem is I have no idea how to use it for this task.

I specifically want an 8-tap Daubechies. My ultimate goal is to be able to predict the next number in a sequence of numbers. [This URL](http://digirep.rhul.ac.uk/file/0034a6af-bae8-1c1c-4a5c-136e9ef34569/1/Murtagh-_Wavelet_based_combined_signal_filtering_and_prediction.pdf) gives all the math, but no code.

I have searched, but cannot find any code on how to do this. Could someone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following FOS C# code: [Wavelet Studio](http://www.waveletstudio.net). It's a good starting point.